# Render partial from helper_method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views, ruby-on-rails-3.1, helpermethods

Ok so I have a helper method in the application controller:

```
def run_test(test_name)
  #computation stuff
  render :partial => test_name
end
```

And I call it like so in views:

```
<%= run_test("testpartial") %>
```

and it renders ok with only 1 (although... the render partial seems to be returning an array instead of just the partial content?), but if I put the run_test helper call in the view twice I get a double render error, which shouldn't be happening with partials.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which versions of ruby and rails are you using, I don't get this behaviour when running 3.1?

Comment: 3.1. I was using an RC candidate but I upgraded just to be sure and it still isn't working.

Comment: Hmmm... So turns out I was defining this helper method in the application_controller using helper_method :run_test however moving it to application_helper file in the helpers folder works. So.. I have a whole in my understanding between the difference of a helper defined in the application controller and a helper defined in a helper file. Anyone able to fill me in?

Comment: A method in the application controller is only available to controllers. A method in a helper is only available to views.

Comment: Thanks John. If you want to add that as an answer I'll gladly mark it as accepted for you :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`render` in a controller versus `render` in a view are different methods.  The controller eventually calls `render` on a view, but the controller's `render` method itself expects to be called only once.  It looks like this:

```
# Check for double render errors and set the content_type after rendering.
def render(*args) #:nodoc:
  raise ::AbstractController::DoubleRenderError if response_body
  super
  self.content_type ||= Mime[formats.first].to_s
  response_body
end
```

Note how it raises if called more than once?

When you call `helper_method` you give the view a proxy to the controller's version of `render`, which is not intended to be used in the same way as `ActionView`'s, which ***is***, unlike the controller's, expected to be called repeated to render partials and whatnot.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like in Rails 3.2 this just works:

```
# application_helper.rb
def render_my_partial
  render "my_partial"
end
```

Comment: This also works in Rails 3.0. This looks like the best answer to me.

Comment: I had to use render "my_partial.html.erb" on a partial named "_my_partial.html.erb" but this worked.

Comment: The question is specifically how to render a partial in a method on the controller exposed by the controller's `helper_method`.  This doesn't address the question.

Answer (score -2):

You could try using `render_to_string` method in the view helper

```
render_to_string :partial => test_name, :layout => false
```

Comment: render_to_string is not available in view helpers.

Comment: For me, this worked. render_partial "/static/partials/rightCol/_related"